# Setting a Flatpak app as the default web browser

Tags: browser, flatpak, file-associations

I run Firefox from a Flatpak but I can't find how to have it open links when I click them in various XDG-compliant apps. How can I have `xdg-open` run Firefox from a Flatpak distribution?

The application itself shows in preferences that it is not the default browser. It offers a button to set itself as default but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the `xdg-settings` command. This should return your current default browser:

```
xdg-settings get default-web-browser
```

To change it to your Flatpak version, do this:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser <your_flatpak_browser.desktop>
```

To validate your new settings, do this:

```
xdg-settings check default-web-browser <your_flatpak_browser.desktop>
```

Comment: I had to scan my whole filesystem to find the .desktop file. It is located in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.mozilla.firefox.desktop`.

Comment: I should have guessed that, but I moved my flatpaks to $HOME so the locations are totally different and I couldn't remember where the default location was.

Comment: The path leading to the directory is somehow already added to the list of directories that XDG will search in, but I had to find the actual name of the file. Then the command `xdg-settings set default-web-browser org.mozilla.firefox.desktop` managed to install it.

Comment: OK, good to know.

Comment: `xdg-settings set default-web-browser com.brave.Browser.desktop` WFM

Comment: Thank you! One-liner for my usecase was: `APPLICATION_ID=$(flatpak list --columns=application | grep firefox) && xdg-settings set default-web-browser ${APPLICATION_ID}.desktop`
Replace firefox with the browser you need.

Comment: For Flatpak-based Chrome from Flathub: `xdg-settings set default-web-browser com.google.Chrome.desktop`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above posted:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser <your_flatpak_browser.desktop>
```

the following settings helped me:

```
xdg-mime default <your_flatpak_browser.desktop> x-scheme-handler/https x-scheme-handler/http
```

E.g.:

```
xdg-mime default org.mozilla.firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/https x-scheme-handler/http             
xdg-settings set default-web-browser org.mozilla.firefox.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Mint (21.2), the best way to set a flatpak-installed Firefox as the default browser was within *Default Applications*, *Web Browser*, then select "*Other...*" and enter

```
flatpak run org.mozilla.firefox "%s"
```